# HTML5 canvas screen to isometric coordinate conversion

Tags: javascript, html5, coordinates, isometric, html-canvas

I am trying to create an isometric game using HTML5 canvas, but don't know how to convert HTML5 canvas screen coordinates to isometric coordinates.
My code now is:

```
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
function mouseCheck(event) {
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
}
```

which gives me canvas coordinates. But how do I convert these coordinates to isometric coordinates? I am using 16x16 tiles.

Comment: 16x16 is squared.. not isometric.

Comment: The answer I gave here might help you, though it uses 64x32 tiles: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/isometric-rendering-and-picking/12389#12389

Comment: @thedaian I'd even say that it's a duplicate of that question.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/ there are some beautiful illustrations :D

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code examples at [Andres Pagella's github repo](https://github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/tree/master/examples). It's the example code that goes along with [his book on isometric social games in HTML5.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020011.do) The book explains the math behind the transformation, or you could try and puzzle it out from one his examples, [like this one](https://github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/blob/master/examples/ex12-isogrid-click.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably going to depend on how you define your world grid, but the tutorials posted earlier are good. I wrote an html5 game engine and open sourced it here: https://github.com/j03m/trafficcone

Docs are still a little rough, but there are some usable/runnable examples. The Isometric game world model shows some of the code needed to do those translations.

Check out this class, it contains a bunch of helper functions designed to hide some of the complexity - but its a bit coupled to how we do things (tiles + cells):

https://github.com/j03m/trafficcone/blob/master/public/tccore/GameWorldModelIso.js

```
 getWorldCellFromScreenCoord: function (screenX, screenY) {
        var pos = this.getCell(screenX, screenY);
        pos.x = pos.x + this.cameraX;
        pos.y = pos.y + this.cameraY;
        return pos;
    },
    getCell: function (screenX, screenY) {

        var screenLocationX = screenX - this.originX;
        var screenLocationY = this.originY - screenY;

        var ym = (2 * screenLocationY - screenLocationX) / 2;

        var xm = screenLocationX + ym;
        var tw = this.cellWidth;
        var th = this.cellHeight;

        if (xm > 0) {
            xm = xm + tw / 2
        }
        else {
            xm = xm - tw / 2;
        }

        if (ym > 0) {
            ym = ym + th / 2
        }
        else {
            ym = ym - th / 2
        }

        var ty = this.rightFloor(ym / th);
        var tx = this.rightFloor(xm / tw);

        return { "x": -tx, "y": -ty };
    }
```

But this is again heavily tied to how you decide to do your coordinate system, the direction of your x/y/z axis (0->max or max->0) and if you use cells.

Comment: You should paste question-specific code here instead of just putting a link to your project.

Comment: Understood - revised.